# How do you base-64 encode a PNG image for use in a data-uri in a CSS file?

Tags: python, css, image, base64, data-uri

I want to base-64 encode a PNG file, to include it in a data:url in my stylesheet. How can I do that?

I’m on a Mac, so something on the Unix command line would work great. A Python-based solution would also be grand.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This should do it in Python:

```
import base64

binary_fc       = open(filepath, 'rb').read()  # fc aka file_content
base64_utf8_str = base64.b64encode(binary_fc).decode('utf-8')

ext     = filepath.split('.')[-1]
dataurl = f'data:image/{ext};base64,{base64_utf8_str}'
```

---

Thanks to @cnst [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375942/how-do-you-base-64-encode-a-png-image-for-use-in-a-data-uri-in-a-css-file#comment28240508_6375973), we need the prefix `data:image/{ext};base64,`

Thanks to @ramazanpolat [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53688522/248616), we need the `decode('utf-8')`

Comment: That looks good. When I try to use the results in my CSS file, Firefox is currently telling me that the image is corrupt or truncated, but I may be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: What does the Base64 output look like, and how do you use it in your CSS?

Comment: @BoltClock: the output I got was `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAP0lEQVQY02P4/fv3f1z4ypUrcDYD\niIOMkQEyH6tCdDEQZkDWRZKJ6CajKEQ3BV0Mr4noGhiw6SbJjVhNJEYhAKztct58fLlaAAAAAElF\nTkSuQmCC\n`. In my CSS file, it looks like `background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAP0lEQVQY02P4/fv3f1z4ypUrcDYD\niIOMkQEyH6tCdDEQZkDWRZKJ6CajKEQ3BV0Mr4noGhiw6SbJjVhNJEYhAKztct58fLlaAAAAAElF\nTkSuQmCC\n);`.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Those `\n`s definitely look out of place in there.

Comment: @Jon: aha! Right: those are newline characters that Python's printing. Turns out I needed to url-encode them so they'd work in the CSS file. I'll amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Miles: ah, are they not required then?

Comment: This works, but the resulting string should additionally be prepended with `"data:image/png;base64,"` -- the code above alone doesn't do that.

Comment: How do you do this in python3

Comment: I tried the original version of this answer that did `.encode("base64")` and it seemed to work but the output was bigger than I thought. I investigated and noticed that it was putting unnecessary newline characters in the output. Also, the `urllib.quote` call was URL-encoding the newlines, which was making them even bigger. I fixed this answer so it does not add unnecessary newlines.

Answer (score 57):

In python3, `base64.b64encode` returns a `bytes` instance, so it's necessary to call `decode` to get a `str`, if you are working with unicode text.

```
# Image data from [Wikipedia][1]
>>>image_data = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x8do&\xe5\x00\x00\x00\x1cIDAT\x08\xd7c\xf8\xff\xff?\xc3\x7f\x06 \x05\xc3 \x12\x84\xd01\xf1\x82X\xcd\x04\x00\x0e\xf55\xcb\xd1\x8e\x0e\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

# String representation of bytes object includes leading "b" and quotes,  
# making the uri invalid.
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(image_data) # Creates a bytes object
>>> 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded)
"data:image/png;base64,b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='"


# Calling .decode() gets us the right representation
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('ascii')
>>> 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded)
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
```

If you are working with `bytes` directly, you can use the output of `base64.b64encode` without further decoding.

```
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(image_data)
>>> b'data:image/png;base64,' + encoded
b'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
```

Answer (score 21):

```
import base64

def image_to_data_url(filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    prefix = f'data:image/{ext};base64,'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        img = f.read()
    return prefix + base64.b64encode(img).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it in **Unix**:

```
b64encode filename.png X | sed '1d;$d' | tr -d '\n' > b64encoded.png
```

The encoded image produced by `b64encode` includes a header and footer and no line longer than 76 characters. This format is typical in SMTP communications.

To make the encoded image embeddable in HTML/CSS, the `sed` and `tr` commands remove the header/footer (first & last lines) and all newlines, respectively.

Then just simply use the long encoded string in **HTML**

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,ENCODED_PNG">
```

or in **CSS**

```
url(data:image/png;base64,ENCODED_PNG)
```

Comment: In some distros there's no `b64encode` included. In that case, you'd want to use `uuencode -m`, which is a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

b64encode is not installed by default in some distros (@Clint Pachl's answer), but python is.

So, just use:

`python -mbase64 image.jpeg | tr -d '\n' > b64encoded.txt`

In order to get base64 encoded image from the command line.

The remaining steps were already answered by @Clint Pachl (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20467682/1522342)

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Python3:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests, base64

def encode_image(image_url):
    buffered = BytesIO(requests.get(image_url).content)
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
    return b'data:image/png;base64,'+image_base64
```

Call decode to get str as in python3 base64.b64encode returns a bytes instance.

Comment: Why did you use bytesio? You can just use directly like image_base64 = base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_url).content)

Answer (score 0):

And just for the record, if you want to do it in Node.js instead:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const base64encodedString = fs.readFileSync('image_file.jpg', {encoding:'base64'});
```