# Unable to render PIL object base64 image on template

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, base64, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to display a PIL object after converting to base64.
I'm getting the base64 value in the src tag but the response is not rendered even after decoding

```
import base64
import io
def newrules(request):
pic = con(select.fname)
print(pic)
buffered = io.BytesIO()
pic.save(buffered, "PNG")
img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
template_code = """
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
{% block pagecontent %}
<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_str }}">
</div>
<div>
{{ img_str }}
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
"""
template = engines['django'].from_string(template_code)
return HttpResponse(template.render(context={'img_str': img_str}))
```

[HTML souce code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znDq0.png)

[terminal API call responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H2OO.png)

[Template rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SAke.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you base-64 encode a PNG image for use in a data-uri in a CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375942/how-do-you-base-64-encode-a-png-image-for-use-in-a-data-uri-in-a-css-file)

Comment: See my Python3 answer in the duplicate - basically you need to do `img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue().decode()` to pass a `str` rather than `bytes` to the template engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()) returns a byte class object. It needs to be converted to a string before passing it to a template. It can be done as follows:

`img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode('ascii')`