# Store an image url in a php form and output it on the next page

Tags: php, image, forms, input

am i doing this right?
i want to put the value of "i.src" into the input and then display the generated image on the other page using the post command

```
  $('#create').bind('click', function(e){
    var datapair = $sigdiv.jSignature("getData", "image") 
    var i = new Image()
    i.src = "data:" + datapair[0] + "," + datapair[1] 
    $('#displayarea2').empty();
$(i).appendTo($("#displayarea2")); // append the image (SVG) to DOM.
    $getElemenById('sig').value = i.src;
$document.getElemenById('sig').value = i.src;//store the value of i.src to input
alert("done1");
})

<input type="image" id="sig" name="sig" />

       <?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>
```

Comment: there's got to be a better approach, to what ever you are trying to do.

Comment: correction insted of <img>  make it <input id="sig" value=" .......">

Comment: you are trying to display the image inline ,instead of specifying a path of the image in img tag

Comment: found out the the value i was looking for is constantly changing every input, sorry i thought it was constant due to the long url, i didn't notice the other codes on the end of the url.

Comment: @NaveenKumar how whould i do that?

Comment: It is a Data URI, Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984433/is-it-more-efficient-to-put-raw-image-data-in-the-src-attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value of a hidden field :

```
<input type=hidden id=sig name=sig>


document.getElemenById('sig').value = myImage.src;
```

But is it advisable ? This is a big string, don't you have other solutions than to pass it to the server just to have it back ? If it's server generated, can't you store it on the server ? Or use ajax so you don't replace the whole page and so you keep the image browser-side ?

Comment: can i do it like this?   getElemenById('i').value = myImage.src; kinda new at this

Comment: how do i get the value of i and store it in a value that can be displayed on the page?